# Questions with multiple excellent answers

Tags: discussion, etiquette

This question is the exact opposite of the one found here:
[What do I do about a question with several partial answers?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/500/what-do-i-do-about-a-question-with-several-partial-answers)

I asked a question and all the answers were enlightening and well worded. If I accept one the choice will be somewhat arbitrary and very subjective indeed.

I suppose the question is one of etiquette. Do people feel competition for accepted answers? Will I slight someone by not picking their equally qualified answer? Is it better in this case to leave the question with no accepted answer?

Comment: You can always upvote the questions but as other's have stated, select the answer that best suits your purpose.  Best is defined however you wish in context of your question and the multiple answers.  :-) Great to see users being considerate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're under no obligation to accept an answer at all; however, accepted simply means that the answer helped *you*, personally, the most, and you should apply that criterion accordingly.

> Do people feel competition for accepted answers?

Some people will get competitive with just about anything.  It depends on the person.

> Will I slight someone by not picking their equally qualified answer?

If they're experienced and tend to answer a lot of questions (and have their answers accepted), they probably won't even notice.  If it's a new user or one with few answers - maybe, maybe not.  Either way, that should *not* be what you base your acceptance on.  Accepting simply says "this was the answer I was looking for."

> Is it better in this case to leave the question with no accepted answer?

It might be.  It depends on the question, and the answers.  It's really up to you.  If you feel that there really was no "best" or even "most helpful" answer, then don't accept one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, if at least one good answer is present, you should **always** accept one. A question without an accepter answer will always look incomplete or abandoned. It is crucial for the community and for the SE model to accept answer.

Between multiple good answers there will be always one somehow better for you. You can upvote all the answers you like, and in the discussion of the accepted one you can explain why it is the accepted one in spite there are other quite good answers.